# Expose class attributes with accessor

Tags: c#, accessor

I don't know the correct technical terms to describe my question, so I'll give an example:

```
    private Point _PrivateVect = new Point();
    public Point Publicvect
    {
        get
        {
            return _PrivateVect;
        }
        set
        {
            _PrivateVect = value;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I wanted to access `Publicvect.X` I get the error `Cannot modify the return value of 'Publicvect' because it is not a variable`.  Is there a way around this?  Or do I just need to do `Publicvect = new Point(NewX, Publicvect.Y);` forever?

Comment: Please show the code that generates that error.

Comment: @Bob: if you think the bolding helped, it didn't. I need to see the actual line of code, and the actual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another reason that mutable structs are evil. One workaround is to expose the dimensions as accessors for convenience:

```
public Point PublicX {
    get {return _PrivateVect.X;}
    set {_PrivateVect.X = value;}
}
public Point PublicY {
    get {return _PrivateVect.Y;}
    set {_PrivateVect.Y = value;}
}
```

But other that this; yes you would need to do the `new Point(x,y)` each time, since `Point` is a struct. When you access it via a property you get a *copy* of it, so if you mutate the copy and then *discard* the copy, you simply lose the change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that the Point type is a `Value Type`. So when you manipulate Pointvect.X you are really manipulating a temporary copy of the value type, which of course has no effect on the original instance.